# Confusion with Kotlin generics

Tags: java, generics, types, type-conversion, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to write code which does something fairly simple, however I cannot figure out how to use generics to get it to work.

I have a `Handler` trait which represents a handler for things. ***I cannot change the code for a Handler as it comes from a library***.

```
trait Handler<T> {
    fun handle(result: T)
}
```

All of the code below is in my control -

`User` is an open class that has subclasses such as `AdminUser` and `GuestUser` etc.

A trait called `AdminUserAction` does something to create a List of AdminUsers and then passes the list to a handler for `List<AdminUser>` -

```
trait AdminUserAction {
    fun then(handler: Handler<List<AdminUser>>)
}
```

Now I want to pass an `AdminUserAction` a handler for `User` instead of `AdminUser`. Let's say the handler simply logs the names of the users, and doesn't do anything with Admin specific properties.

```
fun doIt(action: AdminUserAction, printAllNames: Handler<List<User>>) {
    action.then(printAllNames)
}
```

However, this code gives me a *TypeMismatch*.

Since the Handler is of the type `List<T>` and is immutable, the preceding code should be completely safe, however the compiler isn't able to figure it out.

If I had access to the code for Handler I could do the following and it would work -

```
trait Handler<in T> {
    fun handle(result: T)
}
```

However, as I said before, I cannot modify Handler as it comes from a library. Also, it seems *hacky* to have to do this because the type of Handler is fully general and should be usable for other kinds of handlers too.

I tried subclassing Handler and using that -

```
trait ListHandler<in T>: Handler<List<T>> { }
```

However now I get an error that says *"Parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'invariant' position in Handler>"*

I tried -

```
trait ListHandler<in T>: Handler<List<in T>> { }
```

But that gives me more errors.

Why is this so confusing? And how can I use generics to get the preceding code to work?

**Edit:**

I can make it work by writing a generic function that converts a `Handler<List<User>>` into `Handler<List<AdminUser>>` -

```
fun <T: User> fromGeneric(handler: Handler<User>): Handler<T> {
    return object: Handler<T> {
        override fun handle(result: List<T>) {
            handler.handle(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And then -

```
fun doIt(action: AdminUserAction, printAllNames: Handler<List<User>>) {
    action.then(fromGeneric(printAllNames))
}
```

But, this seems so wasteful. Especially look at the body of the conversion function `fromGeneric`. It is doing **nothing**! Yet I have to go through the rigamarole of using it everytime just to satisfy the types.

Is there a better way? Is it technically possible to make the Kotlin compiler smarter so that this type jugglery is not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions:

Change the definition of `AdminUserAction` to

```
trait AdminUserAction {
    fun then(handler: Handler<in List<AdminUser>>)
}
```

or change the definition of `AdminUserAction` to

```
trait AdminUserAction {
    fun then(handler: Handler<List<User>>)
}
```

or just cast `printAllNames` like this

```
fun doIt(action: AdminUserAction, printAllNames: Handler<List<User>>) {
    action.then(printAllNames as Handler<List<AdminUser>>)
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 and 2 may work but restrict my ability to use `AdminUserAction` in other contexts. Solution 3 is not desirable because we lose type safety.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can solve the problem with - `trait ListHandler<in T>: Handler<List<T>> { }`? That would be the neatest solution IMO

Comment: The problem ultimately lies in the fact that you can't change the Handler trait. Handler is really a consumer (as described in http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) hence T should be declared as in. Because it isn't, you need some sort of hack anyway. And as far as I can see, solution 1 comes closest to the real solution. Also I don't see how that limits your usage of AdminUserAction. From a type-system point of view, it makes sense.

Comment: Yup, still hoping for a good solution that doesn't require me defining my own Handler type, because then I'd have to keep converting *that* type to the library Handler all over the place.