# Subclassing a class to change the varience of a type parameter in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, kotlin

This question is derived from [my previous question on Kotlin Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29984417/348716). Please look there for more information on the motivation behind this question.

I have a class that takes an unconstrained type parameter

```
trait Handler<T> {
    fun handle(result: T)
}
```

I need to create a `Handler` instance where `T` is a `List<O>`, and is therefore immutable. My thought was to subclass `Handler` and annotate it as a Consumer (i.e. by using `in`) -

```
trait ListHandler<in T>: Handler<List<T>> { }
```

However this gives me an error that says ***"Parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'invariant' position in `Handler<List<T>`"***

What does the error mean, and is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that, for all the compiler knows, your declarations may lead to a runtime failure. Keep in mind that when checking `ListHandler` the compiler does not know what members are defined inside `Handler`, all it knows is that `Handler` has been successfully type-checked, and that its signature says that the type parameter is invariant. This is necessary, because `Handler` may be changed later and recompiled without recompiling `ListHandler`:

```
trait Handler<T> {
    fun handle(result: T)
    fun get() : T
}
```

With such a declaration, it is easy to write a breaking piece of code:

```
// an ill-behaved ListHandler
class HandlerImpl<T> : ListHandler<T> {
    private var storage: List<T> = listOf()    
    override fun handle(result: List<T>) { storage = result }    
    override fun get(): List<T> = storage    
}

// Code using it, that breaks
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val anyHandler = HandlerImpl<Any>()
    anyHandler.handle(listOf(1, 2, 3))

    val problematic: ListHandler<String> = anyHandler
    // The following line requires an element to be a String, but it is an Int
    problematic.get()[0].length() 
}
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

See full code [here](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/10407497156101730877156660208/104074971561017308771-526712749).

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying now - "This is necessary, because Handler may be changed later and recompiled without recompiling ListHandler". So Kotlin cannot check the members of Handler while compiling ListHandler. Makes sense!